# Vitamin B3 and staph

Tags: medications, infection, research, vitamin-b, staph-infections

In 2015, researchers [found](https://www.foxnews.com/health/large-doses-of-vitamin-b3-may-treat-staph-infections-study-says.amp) that vitamin B3 might help aid in fighting staph bacteria. Has there been any progress on this since then?